# Switching between websites using URL

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, websites

If I set up two websites Website1 and Website2 on a single domain, is it possible to switch between them using a URL change e.g. equivalent of adding "?___store="? I want to be able to quickly check Website2 if I am currently on Website1.

There are three websites, three store views.

**Website Name**; **Store View Name**

- company_gbp; company_gbp_en
- company_usd; company_usd_en
- company_eur; company_eur_en

Entering http://www.company.com/?___store=company_usd or http://www.company.com/?___store=company_usd_en doesn't show me the US store as I'd expect.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks, I have search everywhere to answer this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer, so posting it here for some other poor unfortunate that needs it (I tore my hair out for days).

Using the notation in my question: http://www.company.com/company_usd_en goes to the USA site. http://www.company.com/company_usd_en/product-one.html goes to a product on the USA site.

Seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 4):

Exactly that way.

```
<url>?___store=<storecode>
```

This only works, if `<url>` exists in the store, if not you should get a `404`.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Try as I might I can't get it to work for me. I will update my question to make it more explicit.